# Xcode: "iOS Deployment Target" not available in "Debug" configuration

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, ios, deployment

so - for an iPhone project in Xcode (version 3.2.4) the project settings offer settings for "Base SDK" as well as "iOS Deployment Target" - the later of which determines what's the lowest iOS version to be supported.

however - this "iOS Deployment Target" option is shown to me only in the "Release" configuration. When I switch to "Debug" this option disappears and minimum iOS version required seems to be automatically set to the same as Base SDK.

The problem is that my iPhone runs on iOS 3.1.2 (and I want it to stay on this version!) - but the recent Xcode versions don't have Base SDK options for these older versions (lowest available Base SDK is 3.2) - so I need the "iOS Deployment Target" option to make it compatible with my phone.

how can I make this option available in Debug Configuration?

Comment: In the 'show' popup, do you have it set to 'All Settings?'

Answer (score 0):

You need to install an older SDK to run anything prior to 3.2, but don't uninstall your latest. Just put the older version in a directory other than /Developer, I use /Xcode personally. Code normally in the new version, then open the older SDK to test your app on your phone.

Most users are 4.0 or above though, so keep that in mind when trying to make your app backwards compatible ([stats from major apps on Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-proportion-of-all-iPhone-owners-use-iOS4-%2a-today)).

Comment: this can't be true - since in release configuration it works just fine

Comment: I've never been able to do a debug build on a device with a version that's before 3.2. I've actually dealt with this before. The only way we could get it to work was using an older SDK.